"OSError: [WinError 126] Issue with PyTorch Import - Error Loading 'fbgemm.dll' on Windows 10"
I'm trying to run a code that throws an error when importing PyTorch. The pip install command works, but the import fails. The error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vinig\OneDrive\Desktop\porraa\porraa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\vinig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\vinig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I've tried reinstalling Python, PyTorch, modifying the PATH, creating a virtual environment, and nothing works.

Next step is to install the Visual C++ runtime.  https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/failed-to-import-pytorch-fbgemm-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-is-missing/201969

Are you using a virus scanner? Has it quarantined this file?

It looks like the issue is with the latest version of the PyTorch package. You should consider rolling back to a previous version until this problem is resolved.
pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

